# how to have border in a div that contains two other divs

Tags: html, css

I am working on a html page where I have a header div that contains two sub div's

link: http://jsbin.com/iladi4/3

I want to have a `bottom-border` for the header div but that border always keeps going on top.  I want the border to be at the bottom.

Please see the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `float:left` in #header [See the Demo](http://jsbin.com/iladi4/5)

Answer (score 2):

Add `overflow: hidden` to the `#header`. Demo at: [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/iladi4/4/).

Comment: great. this works. i cant accept answer yet ...have to wait 9 more minutes. but can you explain why overflow is needed?

Comment: Because, once floated, the two `div`s are removed from the document's flow which causes the parent `div` (`#header`) to be empty. Using `overflow: hidden` forces the `#header` to wrap around the floated elements.

Comment: @Josh, did this answer your question in the end?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the inner divs aren't actually *in* #header.  By floating them you've removed them from the normal layout.  Floating #header will fix that problem but may require other tweaks to get what you want.

Comment: Just had a look at the example in @vinothkumar's answer - this forces the div to appear on the left hand side. I think @David Thomas got the correct answer - I cant explain why `overflow: hidden` would cause this though.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a div below the nav div with `style="clear: both;"` this isn't pretty, but it works if for some reason you can't use either of the other two suggestions.