# Why does setting overflow alter layout of child elements?

Tags: css, css-float, overflow

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956599/how-to-have-border-in-a-div-that-contains-two-other-divs/3956612) someone was having a layout problem because they had two floated divs inside a non-floated div.  I suggested adding `float: left` to their outer div, which does fix the problem.  Someone else suggested adding `overflow: hidden`, which to my surprise, also worked.

This doesn't seem at all like the purpose of of `overflow: hidden`.  Clearly overflow: hidden causes elements to view their children differently somehow.  What I'm really trying to understand is *what* that difference is. Intuitively it should only make the element smaller than it would otherwise be, never bigger and I don't see why it would affect the layout hierarchy.

Can anyone explain why this would be correct/necessary behavior or if this is just a browser quirk?  Is their another facet to the overflow property I'm missing?  Is either solution any better than the other?

Edit: I've discovered setting `overflow: auto` works too, so it doesn't seem to be the value of overflow that's important, just that it's set.  I still don't understand why.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Overflow of anything but `visible` creates a new block formatting context which causes floats to be contained. It's standard behaviour.

> Floats, absolutely positioned
>   elements, inline-blocks, table-cells,
>   table-captions, and elements with
>   'overflow' other than 'visible'
>   (except when that value has been
>   propagated to the viewport) establish
>   new block formatting contexts.
>
> In a block formatting context, boxes
>   are laid out one after the other,
>   vertically, beginning at the top of a
>   containing block. The vertical
>   distance between two sibling boxes is
>   determined by the 'margin' properties.
>   Vertical margins between adjacent
>   block boxes in a block formatting
>   context collapse.
>
> In a block formatting context, each
>   box's left outer edge touches the left
>   edge of the containing block (for
>   right-to-left formatting, right edges
>   touch). This is true even in the
>   presence of floats (although a box's
>   line boxes may shrink due to the
>   floats), unless the box establishes a
>   new block formatting context (in which
>   case the box itself may become
>   narrower due to the floats).

Comment: Just to be completely clear, do you mean 'standard' in that all browsers do it, or that's is a required part of implementing the overflow setting?

Comment: @bemace - its part of the spec. IE6 doesnt comply. IE7+ does. Rest of the browsers do.

Answer (score 0):

Floating items removes them from the normal layout *in many cases*. It's not exactly like or unlike `position: absolute;` in that. Block items tend to ignore floated items (including block items that contain the item), but unlike `position: absolute;` items, floated ones are recognized and wrapped around by inline items, like text.

Having the wrapping item (div or otherwise) also be floated causes it to behave differently related to floated items it contains. Having the wrapping item set to `overflow: hidden;` forces it to consider the items it contains differently, as well. My guess is it's just a happy coincidence that the end result here appears to be the same. Not a quirk or bug... just how it works out.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, I'm just hoping someone can better explain what the difference is that results in this behavior.

Comment: I actually hope so, too; I'd like to know more exactly why that is. In fact, I was going to enter my info as a comment, not an answer, but I knew it would be too long to really fit as a comment. :P