# Why does wrapping div not expand around floating elements?

Tags: css, css-float

I have two columns in a center column. (They are all div tags.) When I set the inner divs to `float:left`, the outer div does not wrap around the inner divs.

Why, and how do I fix that?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

set `overflow: auto` on the outer div.

[Why does setting overflow alter layout of child elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956645/why-does-setting-overflow-alter-layout-of-child-elements)

Comment: It might be prudent to a class where you do this to only specific elements rather than changing preexisting classes to that.

Answer (score -3):

set overflow:visible for that div, or remove overflow property.