# How to have two items be placed next to each other in HTML?

Tags: css, html, video

I have a tag called   and in between that I have a video. The video takes up around 65% of the screen. Now in the remaining space, I would like to put an aside, still within the   tags. I would also like the aside to have a border (which I know how to do.) My issue here is I can make aside. This is what I have in a basic format: 
`<section> <video> MY VID's info </video> <aside> my aside </aside> </section>`
And in my CSS I have something like: 
`section video{ width: 65%; } section aside{width: 30%;}` Now when I run this code, I do get a video and an aside, but they are not next to each other. The video is in the `<section>` area and the `<aside>` is right in between the `<section>` and the `<footer>`. Not next to the video. So if you ran the code, you would see the video and a big and empty space right next to it. And then the aside would be in the location I described previously. Can anyone guide my to know how I should compose my code so that I get the desired result? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803023/how-to-place-two-divs-next-to-each-other?rq=1

Comment: Hello Paulie_D I do have my desired behavior, which is I would like my video and aside to be next to each other. My specific problem is that when I try to put them next to each other, the aside always ends up going under the section. In terms of reproducing my code, that is what I have, unless if you require the actual video name which won't work because you are not using my computer. I will take a look at the duplicate.

Comment: Great...so now all you have to do is make a demo....you can use any video or even just a div instead if you want...should work the same.

Comment: I have to make a demo, video?

Comment: Nope put your code into something like a JSfiddle.net demo and [edit] the link into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the float property to the video tag. Give float: left. This will help you achieve what you want.

Comment: Umm, exactly how do I had that to the video tag? Do I do this: `<video width= "100px" height="450px" float: left autoplay>` ?

Comment: In your css where you have section video{ width: 65%; } add float:left; so the css now becomes section video{ width: 65%;  float:left;}

Comment: Now even if I add that I still have my aside on the bottom of the video.

Comment: Can you post a demo please? It will help us understand where is the problem.

Comment: I really do not know what a demo is.

Comment: Hey! That fiddle you showed me is exactly what I needed! I will take a closer look at it and report back!

Comment: That fiddle was EXACTLY what I was asking for. It was like you somehow went into my mind and found the right pieces thank you King Size and thank you Pauline up there you helped me out to, but King Size is the one that I needed and it was the exact pinpoint.