# Issue with divs side by side

Tags: html, css

I have 4 HTML elements in a parent div ( "header" ) and I am trying to display the child div's side by side. The problem is that the background color of the div "headerTitle" spills out. How do i restrict the background color to just the font itself? And also if you look at the snapshot, the HTML elements towards the left are getting displaced to below the line ( they are not in line with the other elements. please help...

**HTML code:**

```
<div id="header" >
   <div id="City1">
        Cities
   </div>
   <div id="headerTitle">
      Happy Stores
   </div>
   <div id="City2">
      Cities
   </div>
   <div id="City3">
      Cities
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS code:**

```
#City1
{
    float:left;
}
#headerTitle
{
    float:center;
    background-color:gray;
}
#City2
{
    float:right;
    padding-left: 5px;
    color:orange;
}
#City3
{
    float:right;
    background-color:pink;
}
```

[image: Snapshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `float: center;` on #headerTitle, that's not a correct value. The only correct values are none, left, right, initial or inherit. Floating is not simply a means to align an element.

You would have to re-align your div's because a right float will be put under a left float if it comes after it. So you'd have to put #city2 and #city3 before #city1, add a `text-align: center` to #header and add a `display: inline-block` to #headerTitle.

Check out my jsFiddle for an example: https://jsfiddle.net/fx3ydcfu/

Comment: No problem, be sure to mark the correct answer if one of these answers work! :)

Answer (score 1):

> How do i restrict the background color to just the font itself?

You would need to add `display:inline;` or `display:inline-block` to `#headerTitle`, depending on your requirements.

> the HTML elements towards the left are getting displaced to below the line

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5803055/1094772) to position your divs side-by-side:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden; /* add this to contain floated children */
}
#first {
    width: 300px;
    float:left; /* add this */
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#second {
    border: 1px solid green;
    float: left; /* add this */
}
```

Comment: He still has a `float: center` on one div, that's not correct either. Check out my answer for a fuller explanation.

Comment: @s1h4d0w I addressed that just before your comment.

Comment: you guys have been very helpful - let me check it out

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is about positioning of elements in the page, It's better to use

```
position:absolute;
left: *px;
top: *px;
```

instead of

```
float:left;
```

& I should say that:

```
float:center;
```

Is not an available value for float property.