# Div Elements to alight right to each other CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make all blue box to align right to each other. How can I set blue boxes to align right to each other?

**The Code (https://jsfiddle.net/58439865/):**

```css
.page2 {
  max-width: 560px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: gray;
  align:right;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
#TimeTable {
  max-width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: blue;
  align: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="vertical-scrolling">     
  <div class="page2" >
    <div id="TimeTable"></div>
    <div id="TimeTable"></div> 
    <div id="TimeTable"></div> 
    <div id="TimeTable"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Before posting a new problem, try finding it in google or stackoverflow previous posts. [Like this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803023/how-to-place-two-divs-next-to-each-other) or [this](overflow.com/questions/446060/css-two-divs-next-to-each-other) or many others

Comment: @AsadAli you can't have same id more than once in a single page, please use class instead...

Comment: Please further explain yourself.

Comment: @theblindprophet i wanted blue boxes to align right of prevous box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#TimeTable{float: left;
width: 100%;}
```

just add this lines

Answer (score 0):

first of all , you must not give same id to more than one element in html.
in case if you want to give same reference to more than one element you must use class instead of id.. so, just replace id with class ,and class with id.
the code blow must work.. reply if you have any problem.

## HTML

```
<section class="vertical-scrolling">     
   <div id="page2" >
       <div class="TimeTable">
       </div>
       <div  class="TimeTable" >
       </div> 
       <div  class="TimeTable" >
       </div> 
       <div  class="TimeTable" >
       </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

try this code in css.

#### CSS

```
#page2{
    max-width: 560px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: gray;
    align:right;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

.TimeTable{
    max-width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```