# Two Circles side by side (responsive)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make two circles appear side by side (responsive).

HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="circle col-sm-6">450 reviews</div>
  <div class="circle col-sm-6">4.2 million readers</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.circle{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:100px;
  font-size:20px;
  color:#fef;
  line-height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  background:#000
}
```

But with this CSS, the circles are below each other.

Inside the circle, is it also possible to have "450" in one line and "reviews" below it. Similarly "4.2 million" in one line and "readers" in another?

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rkEMR/9393/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to place two divs next to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803023/how-to-place-two-divs-next-to-each-other)

Comment: Thanks @Pete. When I add the br tag, it shows only the first line. The second line is probably thrown out of the circle.

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine, all I have changed is the breakpoint (sm to xs) and everything works: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/42567/

Comment: I have added a demo link.

Comment: I don't see any Bootstrap being used in your "live demo". Also, the circles have fixed width and height. Why is this question tagged with Bootstrap if you aren't actually using Bootstrap anywhere? And what exactly is supposed to be "responsive" if the circles have fixed width and height??

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?? Bootstrap will stack those `.col-sm-6` elements when the device width < 765px so you would need to add an additional media-query to get them side by side on small devices. If you're NOT using bootstrap then just use `display:inline-block;` rather than `float:left;`

Answer (score 0):

try llike this:

```
  .circle
   {
    float:left; //to put side by side
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:100px;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#fef;
    line-height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#000
  }
```

Comment: Thanks and can you also answer how to have "450" in one line and "reviews" below it. Similarly "4.2 million" in one line and "readers" in another? br tag is not doing the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I would make your items inline flex  to make them on the same line (and to centre the content), and remove your boostrap classes:

```css
.circle {
  display: inline-flex;         /* use this so theat items are on same line */
                                
  justify-content: center;      /* by using above, you can vertical and horizontal align without the need for a stupid line-height hack*/
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fef;
  background: #000
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="circle">450
    <br> reviews </div>
  <div class="circle">4.2 million
    <br> readers </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic. Will this work on all browsers including IE 10, 11?

Comment: Not sure about ie10 - think it should do but definitely works in ie11

Comment: Ok let me try and see. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your markup a little bit by using `row` and `container-fluid`...

Also you will need to wrap your inner text into a `<p>` tag and use `transform:translate(-50%, -50%)` and `position:absolute` combination to center the text

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.circle {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fef;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
}

.circle p {
  margin: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="conatiner-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="circle">
        <p>450
          <br> reviews</p>
      </div>
      <div class="circle">
        <p>4.2 million
          <br> readers</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You mistyped "container-fluid" to "conatiner-fluid" but I get your point. Thanks.