# div table not working with float left and right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make this table only by using divs because I will use Angular Components in it and, as I know, it's not working with table tag.

[image]

This is my code by now,
https://codepen.io/teodora-malec/pen/vQdJPr

I tried `display: block` for month, kv, date and tag and it worked and then I tried

```
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="left">
          <label class="month">MONTH</label>
      </div>
      <div class="right month-name">
          <label> MONTH-NAME & YEAR </label> 
      </div>
  </div>
```

because I tried the solution from this question: [How to place two divs next to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803023/how-to-place-two-divs-next-to-each-other) 
and it looks like this

[image]

should I put the divs differently or my css code is wrong?

Comment: as per the stackvoerflow link you have mentioned, you have to add `overflow:hidden;` to the class **month-header**. you can find the edited pen here. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VVQqLP.

Comment: that is true, but that overflow propery didn't change anything...

Comment: please go through the pen i linked above. I can see the Month, KV labels getting inside the box unlike the screenshot you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good practice to use the class "clearfix", while playing around with float.  Here is the link:[What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-a-clearfix)

Secondly, your structure needs to be slightly modified for better /efficient coding. Though I have adjusted your needs in the provided solution, but my suggestion would be to go through your structure design once again.
Here is the working demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/posywj78/

Html

```
<div class="month-header">
  <div class="wrapper clearfix">
      <div class="left">
          <label class="month">MONTH</label>
      </div>
      <div class="right month-name">
          <label> MONTH-NAME & YEAR </label> 
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper clearfix">
      <div class="left">
          <label class="kw">KV</label>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
  
      </div>
  </div>
    <div class="wrapper clearfix">
        <div class="left">
            <label class="date">DATE</label>
         </div>
         <div class="right">

         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper clearfix">
        <div class="left">
            <label class="tag">TAG</label>
        </div>
        <div class="right">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will have a look for clearfix, thanks a lot! Have you changed the structure in the link from codepen? Because I don't see any difference..

Comment: Hi , was updating it , plz check it now  and let me know .

Comment: I have a question... how cand i make the MONTH-NAME & YEAR div to have the width as large as the space remaning. the way it is in the first photo of my post

Comment: you need to set width of both the divs manually. For faster implementation working of these grids/width, try going trough bootstrap tutorial: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

**You should use below style.**

```
<style>
.month, .kw, .date, .tag {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}
</style>
```