# How to place two poll everywhere items side by side using HTML?

Tags: html, css, polling, blackboard

I'd like to place these two poll everywhere polls (embed code retrieved from poll everywhere) side by side on a Blackboard course (LMS) instead of stacking.

Comment: is it possible to use absolute positioning with viewport units? (position:absolute; left:15vw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never seen the embed code from poll everywhere, maybe you can add some example to your post and format it with the Code sample button here.

But independent from that I think: You should create two DIV elements on your website and format both with some CSS so it's possible to arange the the div-containers.

You put each embed code into one div container.

Here is some example to put div container next to each other

[How to place two divs next to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803023/how-to-place-two-divs-next-to-each-other)

Updated solution:

```
<style>

#wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding:10px;
    width:750px;
}
#first {
    width: 350px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding:10px;
}
#second {
    left:10px;
    width: 350px;
    position:relative;
    margin-left: 15%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding:10px;
}

</style>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="first">
        <script src="https://www.polleverywhere.com/multiple_choice_polls/9CQBE41uxfGEYOgydZSJ8/web.js?height=500&amp;results_count_format=percent&amp;width=350" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </div>
    <div id="second">
        <script src="https://www.polleverywhere.com/multiple_choice_polls/9CQBE41uxfGEYOgydZSJ8/web.js?height=500&amp;results_count_format=percent&amp;width=350" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Testlink: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G93YUI61BHFK

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I've tried using div code with no success. Here is the code for one poll: <script src="https://www.polleverywhere.com/multiple_choice_polls/9CQBE41uxfGEYOgydZSJ8/web.js?height=500&amp;results_count_format=percent&amp;width=350" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Hello, thanks for the snippet, I coded a very simple example. It has inline css, if you learn how CSS, HTML and DIV works you can improve it. Normaly you should avoid inline css. But I think it is a right way to start and learn. I added in two divs the same poll you can replace the second one.

If you click on testlink you see some example in your browser. So you can test and improve it, directly. You need to click on RUN in the website.

Comment: Yeah, great. If you have questions ask - here on stackoverflow you can learn so much! I love it here it is a nice place.