# How to place two divs next to each other within another div using css?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I have a labelname and its value within div tag and in another div tag, I have added a button. I want the labelname, its value and the button to be in the same line or row. below is my code typescript and react.

```
render = () => {
    return (
        <Wrapper>
          <Count>
          <SpanComponent>
            Counter value
          </LabelComponent>
          <SpanComponent
            color={
              counter === 0
                ? 'red'
                : counter === 1
                ? 'blue'
                : 'green'
            }
          >
            {' '}
            {counter}
          </SpanComponent>
          </Count>
          <ButtonWrapper>
            <Button>
              Button
            </Button>
          </ButtonWrapper>
        </Wrapper>

    )
}

const ButtonWrapper = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
```

`;

```
const LabelComponent = styled.span<Props>`
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: ${props => props.lineh || 1.5};
    text-align: ${props => props.align || 'initial'};
`;
```

With the above code, it looks like below,
[image]

Could someone help me put the labelname, value and the button in the same line...
something like below,

```
Counter value 0                       Button
```

Thanks.

Comment: flexbox would be a good usage here. for `Wrapper` put in `display: flex;` and `align-items: space-between;`

Comment: You could put them in a Flex box, the default of `display: flex` is a row container. Try making them inline elements or a few different things to center evenly. Let us know your attempts!

Comment: ^ ammendment to my previous comment its `justify-content` not `align-items` I still mix those up from time to time :D. see my answer for more details

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to place two divs next to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803023/how-to-place-two-divs-next-to-each-other)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to tell the parent div how to lay its children out. I see you are using `flex` already on the button. Just use it on `Wrapper`

```
Const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* ... rest of your styles here */
`
```

[Here's an example of it live](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-3wr96)

Answer (score 0):

try display: inline-block for the child elements