# Bootstrap 4 using sticky and float on divs

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 with `float-left` and `float-right` classes that keep my 2 divs left and right of each other and works great, but I want the right div to be `sticky` as well, but this doesnt seem to work. I am using `position-sticky` on the div using `float-right`

**Float class Reference here**:  [Float URL](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/)

**Sticky class Reference**: [Position URL](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/)

Essentially my HTML looks like this:

```
<section class="section">
<div class="float-left col-md-8">
    <div class="row sameheight-container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
           @*Form fields, such as input, select etc.*@
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="float-right col-md-4 position-sticky">
    <div class="row sameheight-container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card card-block sameheight-item">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Total</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>5</td>
                            <td>10</td>
                            <td>50</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please note that the first Div has a bunch of form controls, so I have removed that and just put a comment in there.

Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Standard float issue. Since float removes the element out of the dom, you're better to use positioning

Comment: I thought it was probably an issue. How do I use positioning to get a div left and right of each other ? Everything I search for refers to using float ?

Comment: add a `.row` element in your section wrapping the 2 `col-md-*` divs they will be placed next to eachother and you can remove the floats

Comment: like this: https://jsfiddle.net/rozd9y16/

Comment: You might be better of reading some more about bootstrap: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21190403/3436942

Comment: Thanks Nico. I made the changes as you mentioned, which put them next to each other(without using float), but the right div is still not sticking :(