# How to put two chips (divs) next to each other?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

Trying to make it so chips can line up next to each other. Once all the chips' width becomes too large, then goes to next line.

Tried using `display:flex` but then div contents mysteriously overflow like this:

[image]

```css
.container {
  width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
}

.contentcard {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-top: -4px;
  margin-right: 200px;
}

h1 {
  fontsize: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

p.descriptionText {
  fontsize: 20px;
  font-weight: light;
}

.chipcontainer {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
}

.typechip {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 25px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  /*#f1f1f1;*/
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.projectcard {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 3px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.projectcard:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="contentcard">
    <h1>Project 1: ADFASASDF </h1>
    <p class="descriptionText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Dui ut ornare lectus sit amet est placerat. Sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat.</p>

    <div class="chipcontainer">
      <div class="typechip">UX design</div>
      <div class="typechip">AI Platform</div>
      <div class="typechip">HTML / CSS</div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="projectcard"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: typo in ❌ `fontsize` need to be ✅ `font-size`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to place two divs next to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803023/how-to-place-two-divs-next-to-each-other)

Comment: posted 5 possible solution see what solve that bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I will show you 5 solution, choose what solves the problem (also added the output of every solution)

---

1. the bug is happening because of `line-height` in `.typechip`,

   because technically without that property, the text inside the chip is correctly within the container.

   [image]

---

2. You also have an explicit `height: 30px` (this means that the text will overflow if is a lot bigger.

   [image]

> if you delete the height property then it will automatically work,
>
>  but it will have a big gap between wrapped text.

---

3. if you don't want a big gap,

    then maybe change the `line-height` to a lower number (in my case 1 so it will be equal to font-size),

    then try to add also more padding on the top/bottom of the chip

   ❌`padding: 0 25px` -> ✅`padding: 10px 25px;`

    [image]

---

4. if you want that chip to not wrap at all,

   use `flex-wrap: wrap` inside parent container `.chipcontainer`

200px [image]

> the problem is that 200px isn't enough, so they will wrap everytime,
>
>  but the text is displayed correctly without deleting any property

250px+ [image]

> ✅ preferred one is 4th solution for me, because is easy and doesn't have side effects (and is more flexible because don't waste space)
>
> like you saw, if the space of container is bigger, then automatically wrap correctly!

---

5. if you don't want they will be wrapped,

   - but still be readable
   - one line text

- then use `grid` with column direction.

  [image]

### the solution: *(see code snippet below)*

> `.chipcontainer` now isn't `flex` anymore, but `grid` with `grid-auto-flow: column;`

> `.typechip` now have a `width` of `max-content` so it will be always in the same line (and get the less space he can without wrapping the content text)

```css
.container {
  width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
}

.contentcard {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-top: -4px;
  margin-right: 200px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

p.descriptionText {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: light;
}

.chipcontainer {
  width: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.typechip {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 25px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  /*#f1f1f1;*/
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: max-content;
}

.projectcard {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 3px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.projectcard:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="contentcard">
    <h1>Project 1: ADFASASDF </h1>
    <p class="descriptionText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Dui ut ornare lectus sit amet est placerat. Sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat.</p>

    <div class="chipcontainer">
      <div class="typechip">UX design</div>
      <div class="typechip">AI Platform</div>
      <div class="typechip">HTML / CSS</div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="projectcard"></div>

</div>
```